# React-Router with React 13.3+

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't figure out how to use any relatively recent (react 13+) version of [React-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) . The example on the current [README](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0-beta1/README.md) suggests integrating it by rendering `Router` directly (with routes defined via child `Route` elements). Another official [overview doc](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router%20Overview) seems to advise using `Router.run`. The react-router [examples](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples) use the former. None work for me: I get different errors depending on use:

- When attempting to use react-router by [rendering the `Router` element directly](https://github.com/nonword/react-router-tests/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/app-router-1.cjsx) I get "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: A  needs a valid Location”
- When attempting to use react-router by [running `Router.run` with routes](https://github.com/nonword/react-router-tests/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/app-router-2.cjsx), I get “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null”

Comment: All code linked above, but I suppose I didn't make that obvious. Sorry. Starting here: https://github.com/nonword/react-router-tests/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components.coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simplified version of how to use it, this is using webpack for requires but this is irrelevant, if you have access to React and Router it will work.

```jsx
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Link = Router.Link;

var Comp0 = require('./comp0.jsx');
var Comp1 = require('./comp1.jsx');
var Comp2 = require('./comp2.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <div >
                <li><Link to="comp0">comp0</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="comp1">comp1</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="comp2">comp2</Link></li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <RouteHandler {...this.props}/>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
    }
});

var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
      <Route name="comp1"  handler={Comp1}/>
      <Route name="comp2"  handler={Comp2}/>
      <DefaultRoute name="comp0"  handler={Comp0}/>
  </Route>
);


Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
   React.render(<Handler />, document.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-router version `0.13.3` with react version `0.13.3` (yes both are same). I use the `Router.run()` way so that the UI can be re-rendered on URL change. I'll show my code that works well for me, it's in ES6 (although shouldn't be too hard to derive ES5 from it):

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Router, { Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router';

// Components
import App from './components/App.js';
import Home from './components/Home.js';
import SampleComponent from './components/SampleComponent.js';

const AppRoutes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home} />
    <Route name="sample" handler={SampleComponent} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(AppRoutes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root />, document.body);
});
```

Make sure the components you specify in `AppRoutes` is accessible (by importing or requiring them). Also in this case I've used `DefaultRoute` for instance in `AppRoutes` - so if you're using similar configurations then make sure you have them available from the react-router export. Hope that's clear.

If you're still facing issues then share your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have an existing example code that you can have reference with - https://github.com/iroy2000/react-reflux-boilerplate-with-webpack

For those who are interested, it is called "React Reflux Workflow Boilerplate", and it is a workflow framework that make life easier for developers by providing a development and production ready build process framework out of the box.